# Microsoft Safety Scanner takes long time to run on window 7

Tags: windows-7

I've Window 7 Home Premium with I5 and 4 GB RAM laptop.
I got it last year.
Recently, I downloaded Microsoft Safety Scanner.
It is being running since last 55 hrs.
Why does it take long time to run?
I've Microsoft applications like Visual Studio 2010 and Sql Server etc...
No games installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that the Safety scanner application must have either hung up or is just taking up too much time for the scanning process, close the application and restart the scanning process once again and see if the time reduces.

Secondly, Why are you using safety scanner, a better option is to use Microsoft`s own anti virus (Microsoft Security Essentials) --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5201

Microsoft safety scanner goes out of date every 10 days because of which you will have to download the new version again and again which would be very frustrating, that's why i recommend that you download Microsoft security essentials for your system from the link i mentioned above since its a complete antivirus solution from Microsoft for free.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ran the Security Essentials. It found 3 viruses. And removed them. As an additional measure, I'm running the Safety Scanner. And also, I can see that the total number of files are changing all the time. So, it is not hanged.

Comment: If you ran security essentials already, then there is no need again to use safety scanner as the virus, malware definition updates are the same in both the products, in-fact Security essentials has a broader coverage, so stay relaxed.                                                  Alternatively, you could also use in Windows malicious software removal tool for aditional checks --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16